# How do I apply the same equation to other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, equations

I have a simple excel sheet with groundwater levels sampled from different wells over time. It looks something like this:
[image]

But with a lot more wells, dates and measurements taken over the course of several years. The reference levels have absolute values (metres above sea level) and the water levels are measured relative to the reference levels. However, I want the water levels to be in meters above sea level as well.

I know I can do a single correction by putting the marker in a new cell and typing, for instance, "=C1-C4", wich subtracts the water level in Well 1 from the reference level. But what is a practical way to apply the same (but adjusted) equation to every other cell? Do I even have to create new cells for the corrected values?

Note that a single well only has one reference level. The only thing that changes are the dates and the water levels.

Comment: If the water levels are measured relative to the reference, then positive numbers mean the level is *higher* than the reference, and negative number would mean the level is *lower*.  Therefore, you need to **add** the measurement to the reference to get the total height above sea level.  Your formula should be =C4+C$1, filled right and down.  See @LPChip 's explanation of absolute addressing.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the water level can never be higher than the reference level (the top of the well). They are measured by lowering a tape line (in lack of better words) into the well. If the well is completely full the value of the water level will be 0.

Comment: Ah, the reference is the height of the well, and the depth *below* the reference is recorded as a positive number.  I get it now, and of course subtracting is the right thing to do.  I'll butt out now.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is very simple.

Type in the formula in one of the cells as it would work for that cell.

Then once you press enter to complete entering the formula in that cell, if the cursor jumped down one cell, move it back up one cell so the cell with the formula is selected.

Notice that little black square in the bottom right of the selected cell?

Move your mouse cursor to that black square and your cursor becomes a +. Now drag that black square down or to the right, depending on where you want the formula's to copy to and make a big selection. Upon releasing the mouse button, the selection is made to accompany all the cells you selected, and they all now have the correct formula.

You can continue to drag the square with this selection set to do the same, so don't worry about not being able to select all single cells in one go.

Alternatively, simply copy/paste the cell to a new cell and it will transpose the formula in the very same way. You can even copy, then make a selection and then paste to paste that formula into the selection.

It may be necessary to prevent either the column or cell number to automatically change. This can be done by writing a $ in your formula.

For example, if you have =C1 and you want to make sure the C remains a C, but the 1 changes, you would write =$C1. If you want the 1 to always stay the same, but the C to change relative to the new cell, you would write =C$1. If you would neither one to change (absolute reference) you would write =$C$1 and of course, if you want both to change, you don't write the $ at all, so =C1 is the one to use. This works every time you write a cell.

Comment: OP will need to use relative and absolute references too,  without that won't be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Not necessarily. But I'll add a paragraph about it. And to whoever downvoted me, why?

Comment: Also the downvote is from me. Because your solution ignores the actual problem.  (Add the same reference value to all values in the column).

Comment: Thank you! That last paragraph solved the problem and I have voted you up.

Comment: Chip, I tossed you a vote after reading your edit, but "C1" is not correct. It's the reference level, which is constant for a column .  See my comment on the question.  Details, details. :-)

Comment: Ah, I didn't actually paid too much attention to the sheet itself. I only explained what they need to know in order to make the changes they seek. I took =C1 as example really.